# GROUP BY clause with alias?

Tags: mysql, group-by, alias

Does anyone know why I am not able to group `TotalSales` in this query and if so how can I fix this:

```
select coalesce(Author_ID, 'All Authors') as Author_ID
, case when Author_ID  is null then ' ' else coalesce(Book_ID, 'All Books') end as Book_ID
, TotalQuantity  
, coalesce(TotalSales, 'No Sales') as TotalSales   
from (    
     select  author_id as Author_ID 
            , book_id as Book_ID
            ,  sum(quantity) as TotalQuantity  
            ,  sum(quantity * order_price) as TotalSales   
            from a_bkinfo.book_authors   
            join a_bkorders.order_details using (book_id)
            where author_sequence = 1           
            group by Author_id, Book_ID, TotalSales with rollup
     ) tbl;
```

I wanted to include 'no sales' under TotalSales when an author has no book sales. Here is the updated version. I'm not positive it is correct but I do have output which seems to solve the problem. Here it is:

```
select coalesce(Author_ID, 'All Authors') as Author_ID
, case when Author_ID is null then ' ' else coalesce(Book_ID, 'All Books') end as Book_ID 
, NumOrders 
, coalesce(TotalSales, 'No Sales') as TotalSales
     from ( select author_id as Author_ID 
            , book_id as Book_ID
            , count(Distinct order_id) AS NumOrders
            ,(Select sum(quantity * order_price) from a_bkorders.order_details) as TotalSales
         from a_bkorders.order_headers
         join a_bkorders.order_details using (order_id) 
         join a_bkinfo.book_authors using (book_id)  
        where author_sequence = 1        
         group by Author_ID, Book_ID, TotalSales with rollup) tbl;
```

Comment: It looks like you don't need to include `TotalSales` in `GROUP BY`. Looking at your query it just doesn't make any sense. Just ditch it from the inner select.

Comment: Can you please explain further? I am having trouble creating the subquery. Should I put this query inside of an outer query??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED2**

1. It looks like you don't need to include TotalSales in GROUP BY. Looking at your query it just doesn't make any sense. Just ditch it from the inner select.
2. To include books that have not been sold you have to use an outer join

That being said your query might look like

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(author_id, 'All Authors') author_id
     , COALESCE(book_id, IF(author_id IS NULL, 'All Books', 'Subtotal')) book_id
     , COALESCE(total_quantity, 'No books') total_quantity
     , COALESCE(total_sales, 'No Sales') total_sales   
 FROM 
(    
 SELECT author_id 
      , b.book_id 
      , SUM(quantity) total_quantity  
      , SUM(quantity * order_price) total_sales   
   FROM book_authors b LEFT JOIN order_details d
     ON b.book_id = d.book_id
  WHERE author_sequence = 1           
  GROUP BY Author_id, Book_ID WITH ROLLUP  -- you don't need TotalSales here
) q;
```

Sample output:

```
+-------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+
| author_id   | book_id   | total_quantity | total_sales |
+-------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+
| 1           | 1         | 12             | 278.50      |
| 1           | 3         | No books       | No Sales    |
| 1           | Subtotal  | 12             | 278.50      |
| 3           | 2         | 5              | 75.75       |
| 3           | Subtotal  | 5              | 75.75       |
| All Authors | All Books | 17             | 354.25      |
+-------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e622f/10)** demo

Comment: But how could I group TotalSales though. I need to include a message that says 'no orders' under TotalSales where there are no orders for a book.

Comment: You answered my question. I took a look a some sample output that was provided and you gave me exactly what I needed. This is still new to me so I am learning along the way. Thank You and problem solved!

Comment: If I need 'anon' for no authors under Author_ID, and 'no books' for no books under Book_ID. How could I incorporate that? I think I am going crazy.

Answer (score 0):

This is how that works (order):

1. `FROM` clause
2. `WHERE` clause
3. `GROUP BY` clause
4. `HAVING` clause
5. `SELECT` clause
6. `ORDER BY` clause

In this case your alias created on 5 step, buy where works on 2 step. You need to create subquery with calculated `TotalSales` and then use `GROUP` in outer query.

Comment: Not exactly sure how to group multiple aliases. I am a beginner and not sure if I should add another subquery  in the where clause or if I should have another subquery in the from clause. Could you please elaborate with a demonstration please?